# Web Api 2 - FromBody object always null when a variable contains ampersand

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api2

I have an endpoint specified that reads the request body using [FromBody], but, the value is always null when one of the fields contains an ampersand (&). The client in question is passing XML to the endpoint.

```
public IHttpActionResult CreateStage([FromBody] JobStageWrapper stage)
```

The JobStageWrapper object

```
public class JobStageWrapper
{
    public JobStage job { get; set; }
}
```

The Stage object

```
public class JobStage
    {
        public string jobno { get; set; }
        // Job Stage
        public string jobStage { get; set; }
        // Stage Date
        public DateTime StageDate { get; set; }
        public string Memo { get; set; }
    }
```

So, for example:

```
<memo>My name is Adam & I live in England</memo>
```

Returns null

```
<memo>My name is Adam and I live in England</memo>
```

Returns a populated object

Is there a way I can intercept the request body to replace these special characters so that the object is always fully populated?

Thanks!
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... one of the fields contains an ampersand (&). The client in question is passing XML to the endpoint.

The client should make sure that the xml is escaped. Ampersand should be passed as `&amp;`

This is not a valid xml element

```
<memo>My name is Adam & I live in England</memo>
```

but this is

```
<memo>My name is Adam &amp; I live in England</memo>
```

---

See [List of XML and HTML character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) -> `Predefined entities in XML` section for a list of special characters in XML that need to be escaped.

Or here is the list copied from this previous answer on SO [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1091945/1260204).

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

Comment: Thank you - very informative response with links to really useful information. Everything is now resolved with the client.